# How to assert if an element is being visually displayed even if it exists in the DOM already?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I am using Capybara/Poltergeist with RSPEC for feature tests. `:js => true` is enabled as well.

After loading the page, when the page is ready, I want to interact with a menu bar that opens and closes via a click, with CSS animation, with content. Now, that content is already on the HTML page however it toggles a CSS class which has a `display: none`.

I do have this snippet to disable transitions in CSS only during tests.

```
- if Rails.env.development?
      :javascript
         var disableAnimationStyles = '-webkit-transition: none !important;' +
                              '-moz-transition: none !important;' +
                              '-ms-transition: none !important;' +
                              '-o-transition: none !important;' +
                              'transition: none !important;'
         window.onload = function() {
           var animationStyles = document.createElement('style');
           animationStyles.type = 'text/css';
           animationStyles.innerHTML = '* {' + disableAnimationStyles + '}';
           document.head.appendChild(animationStyles);
         };
```

Picture 1 (Opened): 
[image: Picture 1 (Opened)]

---

Picture 2 (Opened):
[image]

---

My first step, I wait for the page to load and I click on the gray square as seen in the pictures and that gray box is supposed to open. So that is Picture 1. And my code passes however what I am looking for (Picture 2) is not displayed.

If I put a `sleep(4)` in before I take a screenshot, I am given the result of Picture 2 but my test passes. This is just a false positive since I just added a sleep there for my screenshot to take it and I assuming its the same assertion as my first example.

(The various commented out code are other things I have tried.)

At the end of the day, I would like to assert if "SILVER (BOXER BRIEFS)" is being successfully displayed visually. I am not sure if Poltergeist/Capybara is just checking to see if that text exists in the HTML source, which I don't want to check.

We were having an issue where the menu would not be displayed however that was because the CSS class "visible" was not being added, but even if I kept that code in the site, this test still passes regardless if the box is displayed or not.

Any suggestions on how to assert if that text is displayed, visually?

My current spec:

```
it "should open all available fabrics" do
      find(:xpath, '//*[@id="sister-selector"]/div/div[3]/div').click
      wait_for_ajax
      expect(page).to have_css('.current-selection.sister-selector-mobile.disclosed')
      expect(page).to have_css('.alternative-selections.sister-selector-mobile.visible')
      take_screenshot
      # expect(find("#sister-selector-mobile#{boxer_briefs_silver.id}").visible?).to be_falsey
      # find(:css, "#sister-selector-mobile#{boxer_briefs_silver.id}").should be_visible
      # expect(find("#sister-selector-mobile#{boxer_briefs_silver.id}", :visible => false)).to have_content(boxer_briefs_silver.name.upcase)
end
```

HTML:

```
<div class="current-selection sister-selector-mobile disclosed">
  <div class="div" style="position: relative">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
    18 Hour Jersey
    <br>
    <span class="category">
      (Boxer Briefs)
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="alternative-selections sister-selector-mobile visible">
  <a href="#" data-navigate="product_detail" data-navigate-options="silver-boxer-brief">
    <div class="selection">
      <div class="the-line"></div>
      <div>
        <div class="heading" id="sister-selector-mobile51">
          Silver
          <br>
          <span class="category">
            (Boxer Briefs)
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" data-navigate="product_detail" data-navigate-options="3x3-boxer-briefs">
    <div class="selection">
      <div class="the-line"></div>
      <div>
        <div class="heading" id="sister-selector-mobile98">
          3x3 Boxer Briefs
          <br>
          <span class="category">
            (Boxer Briefs)
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you done something silly like set `Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = false` or  `Capybara.visible_text_only = false` ?

Comment: I have neither set anywhere @TomWalpole

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't changed the Capybara defaults for visibility checks it should just be

```
expect(page).to have_content(boxer_briefs_silver.name.upcase)
```

or if you want to ensure its scoped to a part of the page, something like this (guessing from your selectors - posting actual html would make this easier)

```
#do your click here
menu_bar = find('#sister-selector')
expect(menu_bar).to have_text(boxer_briefs_silver.name.upcase)
```

Also, I see your test doesn't have `js: true` metadata, so I assume you have Capybara.default_driver set as :poltergeist - otherwise JS won't be supported and is needed for this test

What this test should really boil down to is

```
it "should open all available fabrics" do
  menu_bar = find('#sister-selector')
  menu_bar.find(:xpath, './/div/div[3]/div').click
  expect(menu_bar).to have_text(boxer_briefs_silver.name.upcase)      
end
```

Comment: I do have it at the top of this entire spec file.

Comment: @reid Aassuming you mean `js: true` - then that should be fine

Comment: Let me give this a shot. Thanks

Comment: I added HTML to my question if you are curious @tom-walpole

Comment: I am guessing this could work as well? `expect(page.evaluate_script('$.find(".alternative-selections.sister-selector-mobile.visible").length')).to eq(1)` @TomWalpole

Comment: Probaby, but it's a terrible solution -- it completely sidesteps Capybaras waiting/retrying behavior and isn't actually checking visiblity (all it checks is that the visible class is there, not that the element is actually visible)

Comment: @reid I updated my answer to what this test should really boil down to, no need for wait_for_ajax, etc, I'm not even sure the xpath is really necessary, but your html doesn't include the #sister-selector element so I'm not fully sure on that -  xpath expressions tend to make tests really brittle as pages change.and should only be used if absolutely necessary

Comment: I was checking how it was performed on Chrome's console and if the element is visible then it returns 1 otherwise it returns 0 if the element wasn't visible. So it seemed to do the same during a run with Poltergeist.

Comment: @reid - yes if the class 'visible' actually works -- it's not checking that the class is working though, it's just checking for the class presence.  Feature tests should be checking for actual visibility not css class name presence